# Elliptical Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, evaluation

I have an integral which can be decomposed into three complete elliptical integrals. I want to know the method by which I can achieve this. The integration is the following:

(4 (-1 + y)^2)/(c Sqrt[y (-1 + y + c y) (c (-2 + y)^2 + (-1 + y) y)])

Integration over y

The limit : (1+4c-Sqrt[1-8c])/(2(1+c)) to  (1+4c+Sqrt[1-8c])/(2(1+c))

Comment: What is the range of integration with respect to `y`? What is range of `c` ? What kind of the limit? Make your question self-consistent, otherwise there are small chances, that you receive any help.

Comment: A direct approach is `Plot[NIntegrate[
  4 (-1 + y)^2/(c Sqrt[
       y (-1 + y + c y) (c (-2 + y)^2 + (-1 + y) y)]), {y, (1 + 4 c - 
      Sqrt[1 - 8 c])/(2 (1 + c)), (1 + 4 c + 
      Sqrt[1 - 8 c])/(2 (1 + c))}], {c, 0, 1/4}]`.

Comment: Even with `$MaxExtraPrecision = 100; c = 1/16;` the `Integrate` command fails.

Comment: we need to do the integration over y and the answer will come in terms of c. It is given that the integration mentioned above can be decomposed into three elliptic integration.

Comment: @ayanrana We can evaluate `Integrate[
 4 (-1 + y)^2/(c Sqrt[y (-1 + y + c y) (c (-2 + y)^2 + (-1 + y) y)]), y,  Assumptions -> c > 0]` and get the answer in 1 second.

Comment: @ayanrana The answer in closed form consist of functions  `EllipticE`, `EllipticF` and `EllipticPi` of `y` and `c`. I am not been able to simplifier  it with `Simplify`  and `FullSimplify` using limits for `y` your have shown.

Answer (score 1):

For `0<c<1/8` the integral is (numerically verified)

```
(-((8192*c^3*(-1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c*(-5 - 2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 2*c)))/((-1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c)^5*Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c]*Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + c*(3 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c))])))*
EllipticE[(2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + 2*c))] + (((4*(1 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + 2*c)))/(c^3*Sqrt[1 + c]*Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + c*(3 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c))]))*
 ((c^(1/2)/4)*Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c] - (Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c]*Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 2*(4 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c])*c])/(4*Sqrt[2]*(1 - 8*c)^(1/4)*(1 + c)^2)) - 
(2048*c*(-1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c*(Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 2*c*(2 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*(2 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - c)*c))))/((-1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c)^5*Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c]*
  Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + c*(3 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c))]))*EllipticK[(2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + 2*c))] + 
((128*(1 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + 2*c))*Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 2*(4 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c])*c]*
 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + 2*c*(3 - 2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 2*c*(1 - 3*Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + c*(-5*(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c]) + 4*c*(-3 - 2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 2*c)))))))/
((1 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c)^(11/2)*((1 - 8*c)^(1/4)*c^(3/2)*(1 + c)^2*Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + 2*c)]*Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + c*(3 - Sqrt[1 - 8*c] + 4*c))])))*
EllipticPi[(2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c), (2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + 2*c))]
```

which may be simplified further (but not by me).
You get the antiderivative like Alex said from

```
Integrate[  4 (-1 + y)^2/(c Sqrt[y (-1 + y + c y) (c (-2 + y)^2 + (-1 + y) y)]), y,  Assumptions -> c > 0],
```

then enter the limits, but with an offset `e` that you later (after simplification) let go to zero, otherwise one gets some indeterminate expressions.
Have fun!

The image shows numeric and symbolic result as function of c:

[image: numeric and symbolic result as function of c]

I could simplify the result (although I said I woudn't do it) to

```
Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - 8 c] - 4 c (1 + 2 c)]/(c^(3/2) (1 + c)^(5/2))*
((1 - Sqrt[1 - 8 c] - 4 c)/(Sqrt[2] c) 
EllipticPi[(2 Sqrt[1 - 8 c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8 c] - 4 c), 
(2 Sqrt[1 - 8 c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8 c] - 4 c (1 + 2 c))] - (1 + Sqrt[1 - 8 c] - 
4 c (1 + 2 c))/(2 Sqrt[2] c ) 
EllipticE[(2 Sqrt[1 - 8 c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8 c] - 4 c (1 + 2 c))] -
Sqrt[2] c EllipticK[(2 Sqrt[1 - 8 c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8 c] - 4 c (1 + 2 c))])
```

Comment: @ayanrana I described the procedure in my answer. The more difficult part is the limit e->0,because Mathematicas Limit command leads to `indeterminate`. You have to apply `Normal[Series[_,{e,0,0}]]` on every term with e in the denominator and incomplete elliptic functions (containing e in their arguments). After that you have to see, what some appearing Floor functions evaluate to. Then e will cancel out and the complete elliptics arise. So it is not just typing input to a notebook, there is more work to do. The thing took me several hours, so I'm not inclined to repeat this exercise...

Comment: @ayanrana How did you know in advance that you expect complete elliptic functions?

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: @ayanrana does your answer look simpler than or similar to mine? There may be some clever substitution of the integration variable that I did not see.

Comment: @ayanrana if you tell me your email I can send you a notebook file

Comment: the series you requested is up to order 3 in c equal to `16 - 4/c + 32*c*EllipticPi[(2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c), (2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c*(1 + 2*c))]`

Comment: Mathematica did not and I could not expand `EllipticPi[(2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c] - 4*c), (2*Sqrt[1 - 8*c])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - 8*c]` into a series of c.

Comment: @ayanrana It would be nice if you accept my answer.